# org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException while using findAll(Iterable<ID> ids) method

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm using Spring JPA to communicate through Hibernate with a Progress OpenEdge database. Everything works fine but now I'm trying to use the findAll(Iterable ids) method in the PagingAndSortingRepository to get a selected list of ItemDescription objects from the database and it doesn't seem to work...

This is my ItemDescription model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ArtOmsPAD", catalog = "MSOFTDB", schema = "PUB")
@IdClass(ItemDescriptionPK.class)
public class ItemDescription implements Serializable
{

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Size(max = 10)
  @Column(name = "ArtGrp", length = 10)
  @Id
  private String itemGroup;
  @Size(max = 70)
  @Column(name = "ArtSymb", length = 70)
  @Id
  private String itemSymbol;
  @Size(max = 4)
  @Column(name = "Taal", length = 4)
  @Id
  private String language;
  @Size(max = 400)
  @Column(name = "Oms", length = 400)
  private String description;
  @Column(name = "record_crc", precision = 17, scale = 2)
  private BigDecimal recordCrc;

  ... (Getters / Setters)
}
```

And my id class...

```
public class ItemDescriptionPK implements Serializable
{

  private String itemGroup;
  private String itemSymbol;
  private String language;

  public ItemDescriptionPK()
  {
  }

  public ItemDescriptionPK(String pItemGroup,
                           String pItemSymbol,
                           String pLanguage)
  {
    this.itemGroup = pItemGroup;
    this.itemSymbol = pItemSymbol;
    this.language = pLanguage;
  }

  ... (Hashcode / Equals)    
}
```

And the service class:

```
@Service("ItemDescriptionService")
public class ItemDescriptionService
{
  @Autowired
  private IItemDescriptionRepository itemDescriptionRepository;

  public Iterable<ItemDescription> findAll(Iterable<ItemDescriptionPK> pItemDescriptionPK)
  {
    return itemDescriptionRepository.findAll(pItemDescriptionPK);
  }

  ... (findOne method)
}
```

I build a list with the ids for all the ItemDescription objects I want to read like this (This is in the service class for ReceiptDetail...):

```
for (ReceiptDetail oReceiptDetail : lReceiptDetail)
{
  oItemDescriptionPK = new ItemDescriptionPK(oReceiptDetail.getItemGroup(),
                                             oReceiptDetail.getItemSymbol(),
                                             vLanguage);
  lItemDescriptionPK.add(oItemDescriptionPK);
}
```

And afterwards I use the following code to actually read the ItemDescription objects:

```
itemDescriptionService.findAll(lItemDescriptionPK);
```

But when this is executed, I get the following exception and stack trace:

```
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [MSoftServlet] in context with path [/Receipt] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value element [itemGroup=12010,itemSymbol= 80 10100 -04 -000 -000,language=N] did not match expected type [java.lang.String (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value element [itemGroup=12010,itemSymbol= 80 10100 -04 -000 -000,language=N] did not match expected type [java.lang.String (n/a)]] with root cause
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value element [itemGroup=12010,itemSymbol= 80 10100 -04 -000 -000,language=N] did not match expected type [java.lang.String (n/a)]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.BaseQueryImpl.validateCollectionValuedParameterBinding(BaseQueryImpl.java:908)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.BaseQueryImpl.validateBinding(BaseQueryImpl.java:878)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.access$000(QueryImpl.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl$ParameterRegistrationImpl.bindValue(QueryImpl.java:248)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.BaseQueryImpl.setParameter(BaseQueryImpl.java:631)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractQueryImpl.setParameter(AbstractQueryImpl.java:180)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.setParameter(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:167)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:280)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:358)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:343)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:155)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.LockModeRepositoryPostProcessor$LockModePopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(LockModeRepositoryPostProcessor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy150.findAll(Unknown Source)
    at com.msoft.service.progress.ItemDescriptionService.findAll(ItemDescriptionService.java:48)
    at com.msoft.service.progress.ReceiptDetailService.findByOfficeAndNumber(ReceiptDetailService.java:67)
    at com.msoft.controller.progress.ReceiptDetailController.findByOfficeAndNumber(ReceiptDetailController.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:301)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1015)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:652)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1575)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1533)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

If I understand the exception correctly, I would think one of the elements in my ItemDescriptionPK class has a wrong datatype, but I don't see anything wrong with it... All three parts of the ID are defined as String (otherwise I would expect the constructor to throw an exception as well...)

So, if anyone could tell me what I'm doing wrong, or can give my directions what I could try to get past this exception, I would be gratefull. And just as a beside... as I'm just learning Java for this project, we're still feeling our way around so variable / method / ... naming might not be completly according to best practices. That's something we still have on our TODO list..;

Thanks in advance,

Heino

Answer (score 0):

You defined an `@Id` of type java.lang.String in your entity. All hibernate tries to do is map the composite key to that column.

Comment: Well, I have to map the fields in my Id class to the corresponding fields in my object class don't I? The findAll method expects an iterable of ItemDescriptionPK objects as input parameter, and it gets a list (which, as far as I know, can be converted to an iterable) of those objects. Is there a way to get this to work somehow?

Comment: Create a field in your class of the composite key type you have defined. Change the @Id annotation from the itemGroup String to the new field.

Comment: Okay, that seems to be working more or less... If I have a findBy in my ItemDescriptionRepository which uses some of the key fields off my model, this no longer works (in my case, I had an findByItemGroupAndItemSymbol). Those fields are no longer available in the model but moved to the PK class and now I get an error that the method can't be generated. So, I guess my question in the previous comment should really be, is there a way to get this to work without removing the option of using those fields in a findBy method?